# Does the scope of the tracking behaviour in EF

Tags: entity-framework

Does the scope of the tracking behaviour in EF remains within the using scope or it gets updated on the global EF settings?

```
using(var context = new DBContext())
{
 context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
}
```

Is it safe to sayAfter this the tracking behaviour should be enabled again?

Comment: Assuming that your DbContext is registered as scoped, making changes to the default tracking behavior on the context level, will persist, but only for the lifespan of the context. 

After it's disposed of, and you spin up a new instance of the DbContext, those changes will not have carried over to the new instance.

Comment: thank you , i did test that and its exactly as what you mentioned.